# Как сделать имитацию background-size: contain на чистом js?

Tags: javascript

1. есть элемент с размером 200px по ширине и 100 по высоте
2. есть контейнер с динамичным размером (можно менять высоту и ширину, например, как в textarea)

Как сделать так,

1. чтобы элемент  сохранял соотношение сторон?
2. и если размер контейнера 500х500, то чтобы элемент растянулся на всю ширину (500px) и на всю возможную высоту (250px), то есть с сохранением соотношения сторон

Необходима реализация именно на JS, так как размеры и элемента и контейнера приходят из json и я не могу применить к этим элементам стили.

Вот иллюстрация:
Красный - контейнер
Зелёный - элемент, который должен динамично подстраиваться под размеры родителя с сохранением соотношения сторон.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что никак не могу разгледеть ваши плоды работ... Не поскажите где они?

Comment: Их нет, потому что я не знаю как решать эту задачу. 
Мне нужно не найти ошибку в уже готовом коде, а помочь решить задачу изначально, хотя бы в общих чертах, куда копать, и можно ли такое сделать вообще.
Не знал, что на stackoverflow доплачивают за сарказм)

Comment: В общем, если вы хотите сами разобратся то изучайте данные темы: [`MutationObserver`](//developer.mozilla.org/Web/API/MutationObserver), [`getBoundingClientRect`](//developer.mozilla.org/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect), [Событие `resize`](//developer.mozilla.org/Web/API/Window/resize_event). `чтобы элемент сохранял соотношение сторон?` - тогда это уже получается `cover`, а не `contain`. В `contain` изображение просто повторяется, а в `cover` старается наложится на весь элемент.

Answer (score 0):

Начнём с самого начала. Во-первых, вот вам разница между

`background-size: cover`

```css
#block {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  outline: 1px solid;
  background-image: url('https://i.bcow.xyz/fMGVpco_d.webp');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="block"><div>
```

И `background-size: contain`

```css
#block {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  outline: 1px solid;
  background-image: url('https://i.bcow.xyz/fMGVpco_d.webp');
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div id="block"><div>
```

И если вы всё-таки хотите `contain`, тогда это будет очень ресурсозатратно и легче тогда будет что-нибудь намудрить CSS, но всё-таки сделать на нём.

---

А теперь вот рассмотрим решение вашей проблемы на JS:

```js
class BackgroundCover {
  constructor(selector) {
    this.el = document.querySelector(selector)
  }

  __setProperties(image) {
    let bcr = this.el.getBoundingClientRect()
    image.style.cssText = `
    position: absolute;
    left: ${bcr.left}px;
    top: ${bcr.top}px;
    width: ${bcr.width}px;
    height: ${bcr.height}px;
    z-index: -1;`
  }

  init(src) {
    let img = document.createElement('img')

    img.src = src
    this.__setProperties(img)
    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(img)

    let obs = new MutationObserver(() => {
      this.__setProperties(img)
    })

    obs.observe(this.el ,{
      attributes: true,
      subtree: true,
      childList: true,
    })

    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      (i < 1 ? window : this.el).addEventListener('resize', () => {this.__setProperties(img)})
    }
  }
}

let selectors = ['#actual', '#left1', '#left2', '#nav']
let images = [
  'https://i.bcow.xyz/fMGVpco_d.webp',
  'https://i.bcow.xyz/6vy9VVS_d.webp',
  'https://i.bcow.xyz/lumjqf8_d.webp',
  'https://i.bcow.xyz/6lhW59S_d.webp',
]

for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  new BackgroundCover(selectors[i] + ' .green')
    .init(images[i])
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.red {
  padding: 2px;
  outline: 2px solid #ea0505;
}

.green {
  padding: 2px;
  outline: 2px solid #05ea05;
}

.green, .red {
  filter: drop-shadow(rgb(0, 0, 0) 0 0 3px);
  display: block;
}

body {
  padding: 5px;
}

#nav {
  width: calc(30% - 6px);
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#nav .green {
  width: 40%;
  height: 16px;
}

#content {
  display: flex;
}

#content > div {
  margin: 10px 5px;
}

#content > :first-child {
  width: 30%;
}

#content > :last-child {
  width: 70%;
}

#left1 {
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#left2 {
  height: 80px;
}

#actual {
  height: 130px;
}

#left1 .green {
  height: 20px;
}

#left2 .green {
  height: 40px;
}

#actual .green {
  height: 50%;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav" class="red">
  <div class="green"></div>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <div>
    <div id="left1" class="red">
      <div class="green"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="left2" class="red">
      <div class="green"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div id="actual" class="red">
      <div class="green"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

В данном случае решение просто покрывает весь задний фон элемента и динамически изменяется, есть ещё одно решение в котором изображение не искажается, но при этом уже задний фон будет замениться чёрным цветом:

```js
class BackgroundCover {
  constructor(selector) {
    this.el = document.querySelector(selector)
  }

  __setProperties(element) {
    let bcr = this.el.getBoundingClientRect()
    let img = element.children[0]
    element.style.cssText = `
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    left: ${bcr.left}px;
    top: ${bcr.top}px;
    width: ${bcr.width}px;
    height: ${bcr.height}px;
    z-index: -1;
    overflow: hidden;`
    img.style.left = 'calc(50% - ' + img.offsetWidth / 2 + 'px)'
  }

  init(src) {
    let bg = document.createElement('div')
    let img = document.createElement('img')

    img.src = src
    img.style.height = '100%'
    img.style.position = 'relative'
    img.onload = function() {
      img.style.left = 'calc(50% - ' + img.offsetWidth / 2 + 'px)'
    }
    bg.appendChild(img)

    this.__setProperties(bg)

    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(bg)

    let obs = new MutationObserver(() => {
      this.__setProperties(bg)
    })

    obs.observe(this.el ,{
      attributes: true,
      subtree: true,
      childList: true,
    })

    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      (i < 1 ? window : this.el).addEventListener('resize', () => {this.__setProperties(bg)})
    }
  }
}

let selectors = ['#actual', '#left1', '#left2', '#nav']
let images = [
  'https://i.bcow.xyz/fMGVpco_d.webp',
  'https://i.bcow.xyz/6vy9VVS_d.webp',
  'https://i.bcow.xyz/lumjqf8_d.webp',
  'https://i.bcow.xyz/6lhW59S_d.webp',
]

for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  new BackgroundCover(selectors[i] + ' .green')
    .init(images[i])
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.red {
  padding: 2px;
  outline: 2px solid #ea0505;
}

.green {
  padding: 2px;
  outline: 2px solid #05ea05;
}

.green, .red {
  filter: drop-shadow(rgb(0, 0, 0) 0 0 3px);
  display: block;
}

body {
  padding: 5px;
}

#nav {
  width: calc(30% - 6px);
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#nav .green {
  width: 40%;
  height: 16px;
}

#content {
  display: flex;
}

#content > div {
  margin: 10px 5px;
}

#content > :first-child {
  width: 30%;
}

#content > :last-child {
  width: 70%;
}

#left1 {
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#left2 {
  height: 80px;
}

#actual {
  height: 130px;
}

#left1 .green {
  height: 20px;
}

#left2 .green {
  height: 40px;
}

#actual .green {
  height: 50%;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav" class="red">
  <div class="green"></div>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <div>
    <div id="left1" class="red">
      <div class="green"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="left2" class="red">
      <div class="green"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div id="actual" class="red">
      <div class="green"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Очень надеюсь что я вас правильно понял и не писал всё зря)

**Если возникли вопросы по коду, обязательно пишите их в комментариях.**

Comment: По поводу cover и contain - всё верно, нужен именно contain. Только, разумеется, без background-reapet. То есть, no-repeat.

Нужен вариант именно без искажения. 

По факту - зелёный блок сейчас и есть правильный результат. Он динамичный и картинка в нём подстраивается под него. Толька картинка должна быть прижата к левому верхнему краю и без заднего чёрного фона.

Красный блок теперь можно убрать из этой схемы) 
Я думал, что зелёный блок это будет картинка, а красный внешняя оболочка.

Comment: @Spawnes картинку можно прижать к левой части убрав код который запускается при загрузке картинки (`img.onload = function() { ... }`) и тот который находится в `__setProperties` (я про `img.style.left = ...`), чёрный задний фон просто и легко убирается со стилей (он тоже в `__setProperties`). Красный блок уже убирать не буду, лень :)